# How to see spark executing status in yarn-cluster mode on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark

I'm running a spark application in yarn-cluster mode on AWS.

[image]
[image]

As you see I can't get any running status from Web.

From console I only get `16/05/26 10:12:01 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1464256533172_0002 (state: RUNNING)` which just indicates it's alive.

+++

Here is a snapshot in yarn-client mode under the same condition.
[image]

It seems OK. At least progress bar has been shown. But even after the finish of execution, it never changed again and still show 0/368 tasks.

By now, I can tell only under yarn-client mode running status can be shown but never be updated... 
So how to show an updatable status under yarn-cluster mode ....

Comment: How did you submit the application ?

Comment: @Koffee `ssh user@host spark-submit --master yarn-cluster main.py`. I'd like to execute spark application by ssh in the noninteractive mode.

Comment: Get log of the application using: yarn logs -applicationId <app ID> is everything ok ? Could you also paste you're code ?

Comment: @Koffee Yeah, everything is OK and I attach some additional information  about yarn-client mode above. You can have a look. I guess the root cause is just related to the Spark Web configuration on AWS.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see any jobs running in your executors. Check your code to see if you have done any action on RDD in your spark job.

Comment: I'm sure some jobs are running  by the logs in console.

Comment: The pic with the executors pasted here shows 0 complete tasks, which means no job has run. Can you paste your code so we can see what is happening.